# Как завершить while true из другой функции telegram api

Tags: python, telegram, бот

```
import telebot
import vk
from random import randint
token = 'telegram token '
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def start(message):
    if message.text == '/spam':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Токен вк:")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_token)     

def get_token(message): 
    global token;
    token = message.text
    yes = len(token)
    print(token)
    if yes==85:
        token = message.text
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Слова для спама')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_mess)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Неправильный токен:")



def get_mess(message):
    global mess2
    mess2 = message.text
    print(token,mess2)
    import time
    while True:
        break
        #таймер что бы не было 2 коментариев под 1 записью
        print('start')
        time.sleep(15)
        #вход в вк
        session = vk.Session(access_token=token)
        api = vk.API(session ,v='5.92', lang='ru')
        #группы по которым будет спамить данный бот
        group_id = '-190886821'
        #выбор метода
        post = api.newsfeed.get(filters='post',counts=1,source_ids=group_id)
        #получение информаций
        postID = post ['items'][0]['post_id']
        like = post['items'][0]['likes']['user_likes']
        #сообщения которые будет использовать бот для спама
        mess = mess2.split(",")
        #ids для спама в файле
        with open("ids.txt") as file:

            ids = file.read().split(",")

                #print('Спам по' + ' ' + str(len(ids)) + ' ' + 'группам')


            #попробуй оставить коментарий
            try:
                from time import strftime
                api.wall.createComment(owner_id=ids[-1],post_id=postID,message=mess[randint(0,len(mess)-1,)])
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Коментарий оставлен' + '' + str(strftime('[%H:%M:%S]')))



                 #исключение ошибки
            except vk.exceptions.VkAPIError:
               print('eror')
               time.sleep(0.6)

            except:
               pass


               #from time import gmtime, strftime
               #print('Не удалось оставить комментарий' + ' ' + str(strftime('[%H:%M:%S]')))
```

Comment: уточните вопрос, в чем именно у вас проблема?

Comment: У Вас получилось? Если получилось, можно отрывок класса и как его реализовали? У меня такая же проблема(

Answer (score 3):

Если я вас верно понял, то вам нужно создать класс и завести переменную класса

`self.running = True`

и добавить в нужном месте цикла условие

```
if not self.running: 
    break
```

Или просто не делать ничего, в зависимости от ваших нужд

В другом методе просто добавьте

```
self.running = False
```